# How to resolve angular.dart routes?

Tags: angularjs, dart, angular-dart, angular-routing

How to resolve angular.dart routes? I want to do something similar to:

```
angular.module('ngRouteExample', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

 $routeProvider
   .when('/Book/:bookId', {
    templateUrl: 'book.html',
    controller: 'BookController',
    resolve: {
      // I will cause a 1 second delay
      delay: function($q, $timeout) {
        var delay = $q.defer();
        $timeout(delay.resolve, 1000);
        return delay.promise;
      }
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might take a look at this tutorial:

https://angulardart.org/tutorial/08-ch06-view.html

Comment: Is there an up to date link for this? There seems to be no tutorial that covers the basic resolution mechanism. Thank you in advance.